# AngularJs text filed value undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have one start date field (date picker) and a client status (drop down) fields.

If I select a date in the date picker, when passing date value to server it is showing `undefined`, but if I type any value with date in that field, that exact value is correctly sent to the server.

Inside the drop down list I am not getting the value it is coming `undefined`.

My code is:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div ng-controller="MyCntrl"  >
                    <select class="form-control"  name="clientname" id="clientname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.clientname" ng-change="change(myColor)" >
                        <option value="">Select Client Name</option>                                
                        <option ng-repeat="color in colors" 
                                value="{{color.value}}" 
                                ng-selected="{{color.value == myColor}}" name="clientname" id="clientname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.clientname">
                          {{color.clientname}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Startdate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">

            <!--   <input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjstartdate" required />-->
<div class="container" id="sandbox-container">
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjstartdate">
<input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjstartdate" required />

    </div>

</div>

 <div class="modal-footer" ng-controller="MyCntrlsave">      
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">         
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="savedetails()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

js code:

<script type="text/javascript">

    function MyCntrlsave($scope,$http) {

        $scope.savedetails = function() {
        var vm = this;
        var  projectname=$scope.vm.prjname;
        var  cilentname=$scope.vm.color;
        var clientstatus=$scope.vm.prjsta;
        var prjstartdate=$scope.vm.prjstartdate;
        var prjenddate=$scope.vm.prjenddate;
        var prjurl=$scope.vm.prjurl;
        alert("projectname::"+projectname)
        alert("prjstartdate::"+prjstartdate)

        }
        }
```

Comment: Is it boostrap.right?

Comment: no i am using jquery with angularjs